# Assigning an async result to a data binding property

Tags: c#-4.0, asynchronous, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, async-await

Below is a sample implementation that uses metro API and data binding (using MVVM) to populate list of folders in a drop down list.

The View model‘s constructor uses SetFolders method (private async), which calls an awaitable method fileService.GetFoldersAsync() to get list of folders. The folders list is then gets assigned to the property called “FoldersList”.  XAML uses this property to populate a drop down list using the data binding.

I wonder is there a better way to set the FoldersList property without having to set it in the constructor as below. I would prefer to call the GetFilesAsync method and set the FilesList property value, when the actual data binding occurs (not during the class init). Since the properties do not support async/await modifiers (as far as I know) I’m struggling to implement a proper solution. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

The code is below.

**ViewModel**

```
public class FileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private readonly IFileService fileService;

    public FileDataViewModel(IFileService fileService)
    {
        this.fileService = fileService;
        SetFolders();
    }

    private async void SetFolders ()
    {
        FoldersList = await fileService.GetFoldersAsync();
    }

    private IEnumerable< IStorageFolder > foldersList;
    public IEnumerable<StorageFolder> FoldersList
    {
        get { return foldersList; }
        private set
        {
            foldersList = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FoldersList"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IFileService and implementation**

```
public interface IFileService    {
    Task<IEnumerable<IStorageFolder>> GetFilesAsync();
  }

public class FileService : IFileService
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<IStorageFolder>> GetFoldersAsync()
    {
        var folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
        return await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would implement it as a lazy property and use `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. We are doing it in several projects and it works well. This way you can guarantee that you are loading data only when needed. Furthermore, if you need to prefetch it, you can always call the load method in the constructor or elsewhere.

As a side note, I personnaly wouldn't expose IStorageFolder directly from my ViewModels.

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
   if(!IsLoading)
  {
    IsLoading = true;
     Folders = new ObservableCollection<Folder>(await fileService.GetFolderAsync());

  }
  IsLoading = false;
}

private ObservableCollection<Folder> _folders;

public  ObservableCollection<Folder> Folders
{
  get
  {
    if(_folders == null)
    {
      LoadData();//Don't await...
    }
    return _folders;

  }
  private set
  {
    SetProperty(ref _folders,value);
  }

}
private bool _isLoading;
public bool IsLoading
{
  get
  {
    return _isLoading;
  }
  private set
  {
    SetProperty(ref _isLoading,value);
  }
}
```

Note that you can use the IsLoading property to display a progress ring for instance. after that the observable collection is loaded, you will be able to refresh it without recreating it. (_folders.Add, _folders.Remove, _folders.Clear...)

Comment: I see a problem with this answer. The getter of the property Folders does not await LoadData which is good as it should block. But in LoadData a function is awaited so control is give back to the caller/property. For me this implies that the _folders is not necessarily initialized and thus the Folders property can return null as well.

Comment: Yes, the control will be given back to the getter. But it's not an issue, as the IsLoading Property will be set to true, signaling that loading is in progress. When the fileService.GetFolderAsync() Task complete, the flow of the LoadData method will continue as expected. It's true that the Folders property will return null at the end of the call. But as soon as the GetFolderAsync() task complete, a PropertyChanged event will be raised.

Comment: In fact, it's true that the Folders property can return true. It works as expected: You don't want to block the call, therefore the Lazy initialization of the data can't happen synchronously. If you need to await LoadData, make it public and await it directly before calling Folders. Otherwise, let the Databinding be updated as soon as the Data is available, or rely on PropertyChanged.

Comment: @Eilistraee - Why did you use SetProperty() to update the IsLoading property variable instead of doing a direct assignment? (E.g. - _isLoading = value; )

Comment: Because the SetProperty Method fires the PropertyChanged event in addition to doing the assignment. This allows the UI to be notified when IsLoading changes.