# Where is the C# SetProperty() method in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, properties, mvvm-light

My app is a C# app that uses MVVM Light and is targeted towards the Windows Phone 7.1 platform.  I have a property in my view model whose source contents is retrieved asynchronously from an external web server via a REST request.  The property is frequently used in bindings with the View's UI elements.

I found this SO post that shows a pattern for doing this correctly.  With this pattern the initial *get* request for the property returns *NULL* if the private data member backing the property has never been set.  When the asynchronous load is completed, a call to **SetProperty()** is made to update the property.  My guess is that this technique is used to avoid triggering a nested call to the *setter* while still raising a property changed event for the property and thereby notifying the UI elements bound to the property.  The *setter* is made private to avoid any outside code from disturbing this pattern:

[Assigning an async result to a data binding property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176349/assigning-an-async-result-to-a-data-binding-property)

The problem is that I can't find an Assembly for WP7 that contains **SetProperty()**.  I found this MVVM sample for WP7 that contained a custom one, but you have to derive from a protected class to use it and I don't want to do that if I can avoid it:

[Windows Store Apps: A Guide for WPF and Silverlight Developers, Part 2](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201303winstore/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5988)

Where can I find the **SetProperty()** method for use with WP7?

Comment: The code in the first link refers to a metro application, so it could be in the metro api. I'm not aware of a method like SetProperty on windows phone 7. That sort of method is usually found within an mvvm framework.

Comment: MvvmLight has a similar method called Set in the ViewModelBase class, but you will still have to do a "variable != value" check before calling the method to prevent raising the PropertyChanged event when assigning the same value.

Comment: That's incorrect, the Set method takes care of checking the value before raising PropertyChanged. In fact, Set returns true if the event was raised, and false otherwise.

Comment: That's good to know. I've been performing a value comparison before calling the Set method. Thanks @LBugnion for the clarification.